# Converting files from a C++ base

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, converters

I'm looking for a way to use ffmpeg from a program in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) to allow super easy and accurate converting by typing only a couple of things in. I have everything all working, except the most important part. The actual converter. Here's my code so far - how do I use ffmpeg in C++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string formatIn;
    std::string FormatOut;
    std::string confirm;
    cout << "select format that file is currently in: mp3, gp3, mp4, flv" << endl;
    cin >> formatIn;
    cout << "original format = " << formatIn << endl;
    cout << "choose your target format: mp3, gp3, mp4, flv" << endl;
    cin >> FormatOut;
    cout << "selected format = " << FormatOut << endl;
    cout << "proceed? ";
    cin >> confirm;
    if(confirm == "yes") {
        cout << "proceeding with operation:" << endl;
        func convert();
    }
    else {
        if(confirm == "no") {
            cout << "canceling,,," << endl;
        }
    }
}

int convert()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Invoke the command-line version (using the `system` call should be fine).  Build a command-line string and then pass it to the `system` call;
- Link to the API and do it directly from code.  API documentation here: http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Comment: how do I make the program recognize ffmpeg though? does it automatically, or does it need a header file?

Comment: If you are invoking from [`std::system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) you just include `<cstdlib>`.  Then, as long as ffmpeg is in the path, you can run it just the same as if you were using the shell.